# What is the proper way to create and dispose a system timer?

Tags: c#, winforms

What is the proper way to create and dispose a system timer my code is as below

```
using System.Timers;
public void StartGetFileTimer(int interval)
{
    if (TIMER_GET_FILE != null)
    {
        StopGetFileTimer();
    }

    try
    {
        if (TIMER_GET_FILE == null)
            {
                TIMER_GET_FILE = new Timer();
                TIMER_GET_FILE.Interval = interval * 1000;
                TIMER_GET_FILE.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(GetLatestFileTimer_tick);
                TIMER_GET_LATEST_FILE.Enabled = true;
                TIMER_GET_FILE.Start();
            }
        else
        {
            //log
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //log
    }
}

public void StopGetFileTimer()
{
    try
    {
        if (TIMER_GET_LATEST_FILE != null)
        {
            TIMER_GET_LATEST_FILE.Elapsed -= new ElapsedEventHandler(GetLatestFileTimer_tick);
            TIMER_GET_LATEST_FILE.Stop();
            TIMER_GET_LATEST_FILE.Enabled = false;
            TIMER_GET_LATEST_FILE.Dispose();
            TIMER_GET_LATEST_FILE = null;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //log
    }

}
```

Comment: See the example in the [Timer.Dispose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zb0225y6(v=vs.110).aspx) event involving callbacks and other method of notification

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the [Dispose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zb0225y6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, but as the documentation says:

> Callbacks can occur after the Dispose() method overload has been
>   called, because the timer queues callbacks for execution by thread
>   pool threads. You can use the Dispose(WaitHandle) method overload to
>   wait until all callbacks have completed.

The [Dispose(WaitHandle)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b97tkt95%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) should be used like:

```
ManualResetEvent resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
Timer.Dispose(resetEvent);
resetEvent.WaitOne();
```